# How to get current month name in bash script

Tags: bash, date

What is the syntax to get the current month name (e.g. jan or feb) in a `bash` script?

Comment: See `man date` for all formatting options.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the `date(1)` command.

For example:

```
date +%b
```

Comment: the output is locale-specific. for example, this will return "1月" if your system locale is set to Japanese, use ````currentmonthname=$(LANG=en_us_88591; date "+%B");```` to get English month name

Comment: @computingfreak, that should rather be `currentmonthname=$(LC_ALL=C date +%B)`. Your approach would only work if `$LANG` was already in the environment and `LC_ALL` was not set and either `en_us_88591` is an existing locale on your system with US English month names or (more likely) it doesn't exist in which case it would default to the C/POSIX locale where month names are in English.

Answer (score 15):

The `strftime(3)` manual (`man 3 strftime`), if installed on your system, will list all formatting strings that may be used with the `date` utility or the `%(...)T` format strings with `printf`.  The manual of the `date` command may also contain the supported formatting strings.

To use one of them, for example `%b` ("the locale's abbreviated month name.") or `%B` ("the locale's full month name"), you use the `+` option for `date`:

```
$ date +%B
December

$ date +%b
Dec

$ date +'%B is abbreviated as "%b"'
December is abbreviated as "Dec"
```

Or, with `printf` (in `ksh93` or `bash` 4.3+):

```
$ printf '%(%B)T\n'
December

$ printf '%(%b)T\n'
Dec

$ printf '%(%B is abbreviated as "%b")T\n'
December is abbreviated as "Dec"
```

To get a lowercased abbreviated month in `bash` (if your locale does not always provide lower-case names of months):

```
$ month=$( date +%b )
$ printf 'It is %s\n' "${month,,}"
It is dec
```

The parameter expansion `${parameter,,pattern}` will modify the case of `$parameter` wherever `pattern` matches. In `${m,,}`, the pattern matches everywhere, so the whole string in `$m` is lower-cased.

Or like in `ksh`, declare the variable as lower case beforehand with:

```
typeset -l month
```

With `bash`'s `printf`, you may automatically insert the generated string in a scalar variable¹ using `-v`:

```
$ printf -v month '%(%b)T'
$ printf 'It is %s\n' "${month,,}"
It is dec
```

---

<sup>¹ or the element of *key* `0` of an array or associative array variable</sup>